# Xmonad starting on screen other than 1

Tags: xmonad, workspaces

Recently Xmonad has started placing me on workspace #3 when it starts up. I'll often get caught off guard by this because I'll go to #2 to do something and when I switch back to #1 nothing is there.

Based on my understanding of the documentation, workspace #1 should be by default on screen #1, workspace #2 on screen #2 (if present), etc. I'm on a laptop and as far as I can tell, just after X starts xrandr reports only one connected screen. Yet for some reason, Xmonad thinks the only connected screen is screen #3.

From the xmonad manpage:

> When running with multiple monitors (Xinerama), each screen has
>   exactly 1 workspace visible. mod-{w,e,r} switch the focus between
>   screens, while shift-mod-{w,e,r} move the current window to that
>   screen. When xmonad starts, workspace 1 is on screen 1, workspace 2 is
>   on screen 2, etc. When switching workspaces to one that is already
>   visible, the current and visible workspaces are swapped.

So when I first launch xmonad, the first window I open is in workspace #3 (I would return to it by pressing mod-3) which the above indicates should only happen if I was staring at screen #3, but pressing <kbd>mod-w</kbd>,<kbd>mod-e</kbd>, or <kbd>mod-r</kbd> does not remove focus from the window like it would if I actually had several monitors attached.

Comment: What do you mean by “screen” here? This word has a technical meaning in this context, but it's extremely rarely used (they're meant to support multiple monitors, but windows can't move between screens, so everybody uses *heads* instead). Xrandr shows monitors and heads, which have nothing to do with workspaces. What makes you think that “Xmonad thinks the only connected screen is screen #3”, and what does that have to do with your problem with workspaces?

Comment: @Gilles I'm using 'screen' in the xmonad sense of the word. i.e. where the focus goes if you hit mod-{w,e,r}. I'm using also workspace in the xmonad sense of the word, which you focus with mod-{1..10}. What I find odd is that upon first login mod-shift-return, mod-2, mod-shift-return, mod-1 leaves me staring at nothing, but if I then mod-3 I'm looking at the first terminal I opened.

Comment: So if I understand your terminology correctly, you use the term head to refer to where focus goes when pressing mod-{w,e,r}. I'm just using the terminology from the xmonad man page. An interesting observation is that xmonad doesn't remove focus from the current window if I do press mod-{w,e,r}, yet it also doesn't leave me on workspace 1 when it starts up either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just hit the same problem that my first screen (laptop) gets the second workspace and my external screen gets the third workspace.

In my situation, the problem is caused by a previously generated `xmonad.state` file in `~/.xmonad/`. Deleting that file solves the problem.

The `xmonad.state` file is generated every time you press `mod+q` to restart xmonad during its execution. The file caused lots of issues, and should be fixed in the next release according to the latest github issue tracker https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/pull/91

Comment: Damn, this has been bothering me for months now. After reading through #91 and #86 it makes perfect sense now.